# Where can I handle Exceptions in MVC Java?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, exception

I am coding GUI application for exchange and synchronize data between company's Accounting software and e-commerce system (internet shop).

I want to create it using MVC (Model-View-Controller) Design Pattern.

Part of my application is function which overwrite e-commerce inventory balance with this from accounting software.

I've got

1. View - JDialog presenting progress of overwriting.
2. Controller - responsible for interaction between db's and view
3. Model - data from dbs and app's settings

When I queuing the database I must catch an exception (ClassNotFound and SQL).

**Where I should create try {} catch {} block? In View? or in Controller?** 
I want to present some JOptionPane with error message and finish some state of application.

Comment: I guess the `try-catch` block should be used, where the real cause of problem lies, that helps you to pin out the problem at the earliest, instead of throwing and catching them somewhere else. Moreover, it's better you go for logging with the help of say [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), that way even if the user misses the Error Message, they can check it out later from the respective file :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have mentioned only checked exceptions.

1. You don't need to catch an exception. You can choose to declare it instead.
2. If you don't want to declare it, you can **wrap** it in a `RuntimeException`.
3. All exceptions from the model should be handled at a single place in code (so-called *exception barrier*) and presented to the Controller in a unified fashion. The Controller's main interest is whether the operation did or did not succeed, it's not interested in the fun details of why it may have failed.
4. Writing your DAO layer (for DB communication) without using something like Spring for declarative transactions, connection pooling, etc. is not recommended.

Comment: Thank You for your replay!

But I don't know spring.

I would like to know what was the reason of exception. Problem with MySQL connection or maybe with Pervasive connection.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky question and is going to come down to how you structure your code.  Generally, if you can, have your models throw the exception in such a way that the view can handle it.  This decouples you model from your view.

There are going to be occasions (such as using JTables or JLists) where this kind of thing isn't possible.  In these situations, if possible, load the "model data" separately (handling any errors) and then pass it into the control (JTable/JList) models.

But again, you are probably going to run into situations where you find yourself with a standard model (such as a table model) and you are reading you data from a separate model (such as resultset or such (only an example) - because performance is improved or what ever) where the model will be presented with the task of trying to deal with the exception.

In this case, I can only suggest you provide your models with some kind of error handler/listener that is capable of reporting the errors back to the UI.  If you can, us an interface, this will allow you to decouple the view/models if you need to.

Just some ideas